# Is there a best-practice for testing special member functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, member

Is there a commonly understood best way to test special member functions? I'm fairly new to C++, but coming from Java, I understand the purpose and usefulness of these functions.

I'm looking for a resource/advice on what's the best (if any) standard practice for testing special member functions.

(P.S I'm looking to test specific code, which I can upload if necessary, but I was hoping to get a general (best/standard) practice)

Comment: What do you mean by _"special"_?

Comment: @AluanHaddad [special member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Special_member_functions).

Comment: Thanks, I never thought that was official terminology.

Comment: There is no standard/best way to test classes and methods in c++ whatsoever, so the answer can only be a bunch of links to different toolkits. (Which explicitly off-topic for the site.)

Answer (score 0):

Every test will test the special member functions (at least, constructor and destructor, but maybe also copy constructor).

A test designed to catch errors in special member functions would avoid doing anything else with the object.  It might also use a special instrumented allocator that checks whether each allocation is properly freed.  (Or you could run the tests in valgrind)